# How do I automate filling a form

Tags: automation, imacros

1. automate the filling process

   1. Click a button
   2. fill the form
   3. click submit then refresh the page
2. Clear browsing history data
3. repeat the process

I tried using imacros but it doesn't clear cookies
so what can I try

Comment: Question is off-topic, but you should look at `selenium`, which supports a number of language bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iMacros is capable of these tasks, if that is your chosen automation tool.  You will need to utilize the following functions:

- Click a button & fill a form: https://wiki.imacros.net/TAG
- Refresh the page: https://wiki.imacros.net/REFRESH
- Clear browsing history data: https://wiki.imacros.net/CLEAR
- Repeat the process: https://wiki.imacros.net/LOOP